# Installed: Ubuntu 18.4 LTS but often Ubuntu 14 (previously installed) boots

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have dual boot, Ubuntu and Windows. I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.4.1 LTS. Occasionally when I boot up the old version 14 starts. The top line of Grub display at boot shows only "Ubuntu"

When I close down the system and boot again 18 may start but sometimes I have to reboot several times before I get the latest Ubuntu.

How do I remove 14[boots and all :)]?

I don't know which version of grub I have - probably not grub2

Answer (score 1):

Whichever version you "update-grub" from will show on top of grub menu the other lower down.

Boot 18.04 and delete partition/s of 14.xx.

```
sudo update-grub
```

and

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks. I did as  you suggested. On sudo reboot 18 booted.

Comment: Thanks. I did as  you suggested & 18 booted.                                                                  Did update-grub. The result follows:  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-67-generic-pae
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 on /dev/sdb1
Found Ubuntu 14.10 (14.10) on /dev/sdb5
How do I remove 14? Delete /dev/sdb5?

Comment: I ran Boot Repair. The result is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zNXdTzFdBk/

Comment: Yes delete sdb5 on gparted to remove Ubuntu 14.10 and sudo update-grub.

Comment: Thanks, 'sudo update-grub' didn't do the job. I made an 14.04 update and after that the 14.04 is UBUNTU and the 18.04 is below in boot menu...